# I can not start my Tor relay on my Fedora system

Tags: configuration, tor-install

This is the lines that I added to the torrc file

```
Nickname    myNiceRelay  # Change "myNiceRelay" to something you like
ContactInfo your@e-mail  # Write your e-mail and be aware it will be published
ORPort      443          # You might use a different port, should you want to
ExitRelay   0
SocksPort   0
```

Then I run this command and it give me a error -

```
systemctl enable --now tor
```

The error I got -

```
Job for tor.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status tor.service" and "journalctl -xeu tor.service" for details.
```

systemctl status tor.service Output -

```
× tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tor.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2023-05-28 16:10:32 IST; 10s ago
    Process: 12103 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/tor --runasdaemon 0 --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --verify-config (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 11ms

May 28 16:10:32 redpepper systemd[1]: tor.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 28 16:10:32 redpepper systemd[1]: Stopped tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
May 28 16:10:32 redpepper systemd[1]: tor.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 28 16:10:32 redpepper systemd[1]: tor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 28 16:10:32 redpepper systemd[1]: Failed to start tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Can you run `/usr/bin/tor --runasdaemon 0 --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --verify-config` and include the log messages?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually *change* ContactInfo and Nickname values - that's why it's failing to start, change them :) You **don't have to** supply ContactInfo